# Perl import some modules in all subclasses

Tags: perl

Perl Moose module automatically imports Strict and Warning module into any subclasses, this from the Moose docs.

I want to implement this logic for my own modules, that's I want to import my own modules to every module that is subclasses my application base module.

Here is example:

```
#============================
package MyBaseClass;
use Moose; 

has config => (
    is => 'rw',
    default => sub { {
        who => 'World',
    } }
);
#============================
package MyClass;
use Moose;
extends qw(MyBaseClass);

sub greet {
my $self = shift;
    printf ("Hello %s\n", $self->config->{who});
}
#============================
package MyLib;
use Moose;
extends qw(MyBaseClass);
sub settings {
}
#============================
package main;

my $object = MyClass->new();

$object->greet();
#============================
```

I want the packge MyLib to be imported to every subclass of the MyBaseClass class.

Comment: why do you want to do that?  usually object oriented modules have nothing they need to export.  is your `package main` and following code supposed to be in a file of its own?  if so, it needs to use MyClass.

Comment: Re "Perl Moose module automatically imports Strict and Warning module into any subclasses", you're wrong. Only the code in scope of `use Moose;` are affected.

Comment: Re "I want the packge MyLib to be imported to every subclass of the MyBaseClass class." That makes no sense. Aside from the fact that you import *from* a package, MyLib doesn't export anything for you to import. You surely mean something else completely, but I have no idea what.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, let's say you want your module `Foo` to import `strict` and `warnings` into any package that does `use Foo`. Here's how you do it:

```
package Foo;
use strict;
use warnings;
sub import {
   strict->import;
   warnings->import;
   ...;   # do other stuff
}
1;
```

Now let's write a script to test that it works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Foo;

$x++;  # this will die if strict is in effect
```

See? It works!

Now, the reason this works is because `strict` and `warnings` are quite magical and have a compile-time lexical effect. In the general case — say, you also want to import `List::Util qw(first)` into your caller, which is much less magical — it won't work. However, [Import::Into](https://metacpan.org/pod/Import%3a%3aInto) has a general solution which works not just for `strict` and `warnings`, but for pretty much any module:

```
package Foo;
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util;
use Import::Into;
sub import {
   my $target = caller;
   strict->import::into($target);
   warnings->import::into($target);
   List::Util->import::into($target, qw(first));
   ...;   # do other stuff
}
1;
```

My module [Syntax::Collector](https://metacpan.org/pod/Syntax%3a%3aCollector) performs a similar trick. Here's how you'd use it:

```
package Foo;
use Syntax::Collector -collect => q{
use strict 0;
use warnings 0;
use List::Util 0 qw(first);
};
1;
```